# Getting Vertex_handles to the points of a delaunay triangulation

Tags: c++, cgal

I want to iterate through all vertices of a `CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2`, but am unable to find documentation about getting all the vertex handles.

The [documentation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/TDS_2_ref/Concept_TriangulationDataStructure_2.html#Cross_link_anchor_751) I found for this explained how to iterate through the triangulation.

```
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> T;
typedef T::Vertex_handle Vh;
typedef T::Vertex_iterator Vi;
for (Vi vi = g.vertices_begin(); vi != g.vertices_end(); vi++) {
    // Vh v = how can I get this?
}
```

However, I cannot find documentation about how to get to the Vertex_handle from the iterator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I was just stupid. Tried some more random things and got that the iterator actually is the handle. Of course I find this out after writing the whole post here :-)

```
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> T; 
typedef T::Vertex_handle Vh; 
typedef T::Vertex_iterator Vi; 
for (Vi vi = g.vertices_begin(); vi != g.vertices_end(); vi++) { 
    Vh v = vi;
}
```